# PHP - Replacing an Unkown FTP link with a Known HTTP link

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have been trying to figure this out but guess it's been a while in PHP.

Say I have links such as:

```
<a href="ftp://ftp.blah.com/duh/file.zip">Some Link</a>
<a href="ftp://ftp.diffrentdomain.com/duh/file.zip">ftp://ftp.blah.com/duh/file.zip</a>
<a href="ftp://duh:duh@blah.com>Cool</a>
<a href="ftp://ftp.domain.com>1234</a>
<a href="ftp.anotherdomain.com">What ever</a>
```

I need to basically replace any of those with:

```
<a href="http://www.blah.com/register.php">http://www.blah.com/register.php</a>
```

I have tried messing with `preg_replace` and `strstr`.

As a note there is more then one url in the string could be 1 to 100 or none at all i tried the below and i get a return of 0 for some reason.

Just can't seem to get it to remove all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="ftp://ftp.blah.com/duh/file.zip">Some Link</a>
<a href="ftp://ftp.diffrentdomain.com/duh/file.zip">
ftp://ftp.blah.com/duh/file.zip</a>
<a href="ftp://duh:duh@blah.com>Cool</a>
<a href="ftp://ftp.domain.com>1234</a>
<a href="ftp.anotherdomain.com">What ever</a>
';

//replace every ftp link in $str
$str = preg_replace('/<a href="ftp.*?<\/a>/s', 
'<a href="http://www.blah.com/register.php">http://www.blah.com/register.php</a>', 
$str);
print $str;
```

prints:

```
<a href="http://www.blah.com/register.php">http://www.blah.com/register.php</a>
<a href="http://www.blah.com/register.php">http://www.blah.com/register.php</a>
<a href="http://www.blah.com/register.php">http://www.blah.com/register.php</a>
<a href="http://www.blah.com/register.php">http://www.blah.com/register.php</a>
<a href="http://www.blah.com/register.php">http://www.blah.com/register.php</a>
```

Comment: Omg duh thanks so much 6 hours on this this did the trick it looks like! Thanks you some much!

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try the below code it will help you.
Here `$url` is your actual url which you want to change

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f)tp?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Hrm tried that i need it to do multiple urls in a string a big string a message board the idea is if your not registered you see no links i have this working for http and attachments just cant seem to get it going for ftp links.